# How to store the output of a command in an array line by line in perl?

Tags: perl

For eg, I want to store the contents of the command `ipconfig` in an array, such that each line of output is stored in a new index of array, i.e.
`array[0]` contains the 1st line output.
`array[1]` contains the 2nd line output and so on.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I would assign the captured output using backticks into a `scalar`, and use `spilt` and reassign it to an `array`. That's one way to go about it.

Comment: No, no, no @Ghost. Backticks in list context already captures the output into an array, one `$/`-ending line per element.

Comment: @mob: Oh! I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for letting me know about this. Will keep this in mind going further

Answer (score 9):

A simple

```
@array = `ipconfig`;
```

does the trick. Note that, as Borodin rightly points out, the array elements so assigned include the newlines.

Comment: @Coder: Remember that each line in the array will be terminated by a newline character which, depending on your application, may need to be chomped.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)